# preg_match: trying to identify number formats

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match

I'm trying to identify not only "numbers" in a string, but tag what type of number it is, such as General, Fraction, Percentile, Ratio etc.

Now if I use a tool like http://rubular.com/, my patterns appear to work fine.

Rules?

```
([-+]?)([0-9]+)([,+]?)([.]?)       //General
([-+]?[0-9.,]+[%])                 //Percent
([0-9]+[\/][0-9]+(?:st|nd|rd|th))  //Fraction
([-+]?[0-9.,]+[:][-+]?[0-9.,]+)    //Ratio
```

Strings to check?

```
1  
1,000  
1.000  
-50.5  
-1:+3  
1,200.6:3.9  
+2:-4  
1/5th  
25%  
25.76%  
1,001%
```

It's when I put them in php (`if`/`elseif`) constructs I always end up with the "general" number?

```
if (preg_match('/([-+]?[0-9.,]+[%])/',$string)) {
    echo " PERCENTILE ";

} elseif (preg_match('/([0-9]+[\/][0-9]+(?:st|nd|rd|th))/',$string)) {
    echo " FRACTION ";

} elseif (preg_match('/([-+]?[0-9.,]+[:][-+]?[0-9.,]+)/',$string)) {
    echo " RATIO ";

} elseif (preg_match('/([-+]?)([0-9]+)([,+]?)([.]?)/',$string)) {
    echo " CARDINAL ";

} else {
    echo " GENERAL ";
}
```

No matter what, it echos "CARDINAL".

Yes, I've tried switching the order (Card/General first, then the others).
Yes, I've tried making them independant IF()s, and in reverse order (most general first).

Nothing appears to work.
Even a Single IF checking for any of the formats simply fails.
Either my rules are stuffed - or I'm doing something blatantly wrong.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UU7Tw4

Comment: Thanks.  It is part of existing code ... so something else somewhere is causing problems (no ideas how/why).

Comment: Okay ... I think I may have figured out my problem ... the value of "string" is Not what it should be in my script (it's breaking it down to a single initial integer).  --  That said ... I would never have figured it without your help, so a Big thank you folks !

Comment: UPDATE:  Thank you all - I got it working.  Very much appreciated, and they all now have ^$ and been tested again.

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding each regular expression with `^` and `$` so that it matches only if it matches the entire string or line. Without these, if a regular expression matches part of a number, then that's still a match. For example, `'1,000'` matches your regular expression for CARDINAL numbers, `/([-+]?)([0-9]+)([,+]?)([.]?)/`, because it matches the substring `'1,'`. If you add `^` and `$`, as in `/^([-+]?)([0-9]+)([,+]?)([.]?)$/`, then it no longer matches.

```
<?php
function check_format($string) {
    if (preg_match('/^([-+]?[0-9.,]+[%])$/',$string)) {
        echo " PERCENTILE ";

    } elseif (preg_match('/^([0-9]+[\/][0-9]+(?:st|nd|rd|th))$/',$string)) {
        echo " FRACTION ";

    } elseif (preg_match('/^([-+]?[0-9.,]+[:][-+]?[0-9.,]+)$/',$string)) {
        echo " RATIO ";

    } elseif (preg_match('/^([-+]?)([0-9]+)([,+]?)([.]?)$/',$string)) {
        echo " CARDINAL ";

    } else {
        echo " GENERAL ";
    }
}

array_map("check_format", array(
    "1",
    "1,000",
    "1.000",
    "-50.5",
    "-1:+3",
    "1,200.6:3.9",
    "+2:-4",
    "1/5th",
    "25%",
    "25.76%",
    "1,001%"
    ));
```

outputs:

```
 CARDINAL  GENERAL  GENERAL  GENERAL  RATIO  RATIO  RATIO  FRACTION  PERCENTILE  PERCENTILE  PERCENTILE
```

**EDIT:** This might be a better regular expression for CARDINAL numbers:

```
/^([-+]?)([0-9]+)(?:,?[0-9]{3})*([.]?)$/
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  It seems to work on it's own without the ^$ framing, but it's good advice anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You error must come from somewhere else, I couldn't reproduce it. Try to put your code in an otherwise empty file to test it by itself and it should work fine.

Test.php:

```
$nums = array(
  '1',
  '1,000',
  '1.000',
  '-50.5',
  '-1:+3',
  '1,200.6:3.9',
  '+2:-4',
  '1/5th',
  '25%',
  '25.76%',
  '1,001%'
);
foreach ($nums as $string) {
  echo $string.': ';
  if (preg_match('/([-+]?[0-9.,]+[%])/',$string)) {
    echo " PERCENTILE ";
  } elseif (preg_match('/([0-9]+[\/][0-9]+(?:st|nd|rd|th))/',$string)) {
    echo " FRACTION ";
  } elseif (preg_match('/([-+]?[0-9.,]+[:][-+]?[0-9.,]+)/',$string)) {
    echo " RATIO ";
  } elseif (preg_match('/([-+]?)([0-9]+)([,+]?)([.]?)/',$string)) {
    echo " CARDINAL ";
  } else {
    echo " GENERAL ";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

$ php test.php

```
1:  CARDINAL 
1,000:  CARDINAL
1.000:  CARDINAL
-50.5:  CARDINAL
-1:+3:  RATIO 
1,200.6:3.9:  RATIO
+2:-4:  RATIO 
1/5th:  FRACTION 
25%:  PERCENTILE
25.76%:  PERCENTILE 
1,001%:  PERCENTILE
```

Comment: Thanks for that (NullUserException ఠ_ఠ has pointed out the same).  Ah well - now I need to trawl/rearrange my exiswting code to see what/where the problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please have a look on this .

<?php 
$num = 12.20

$num = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', num));

// output will be 12.2

//it always replace zero and you have number 12.00 then output will be 12
$num = 12.00

$num = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', num));
// output will be 12
```